# how to insert sql dump into remote mysql server using PuTTY?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, putty

Hi I want to insert sql database dump file in remote mysql server machine. i am using currently putty tool for doing this task.  i have used lot of command but i am not able to do this. and i have also created database on that server but now i want insert database sql dump from server directory into mysql server.

I have also uploaded sql dump into home directory RHEL OS remote server machine.

i have used some command like -

```
mysql> use database_name;
mysql> mysql -u username -p database_name < /home/dump.sql;
mysql> mysql -u username -h host_ip -p database < /home/dump.sql;
mysql> mysql -u username -h host_ip -p database < /home/dump.sql;
mysql> mysql -u username -h host_ip -p dbpass -d database < /home/dump.sql;
mysql> mysql -u username -h host_ip database < /home/dump.sql;
mysql> plink mysql -u username -h host_ip -p database < /home/dump.sql;
```

and other command but i could not import sql dump into db server.

Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: 1. This is not about java; 2. question belongs to another subsite of stackexcange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you are missing the password after -p syntax is

mysql -u username -p password db_name < /home/dump.sql

other possibility is that you are not providing proper directory or complete path of dump file

Comment: I have used dbpassword after -p syntax. but issue still present. i have upload my sql dump in server machine home folder. this server is rhel os machine.

Comment: what error are you getting after running the command?

Comment: I am getting - ERROR 1064(4200): you have a error in your mysql syntax; ................................

Comment: and now write here the exact command which u run